# Formatting JSON for Angular data binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

when my ajax call completes an array of  json is returned[image]

for my angular data binding to work perfectly, i need to merge all values in to a single JSON file. I have tried $.extend(), it's giving following output
[image]

Need a solution for this

for example if my response looks like this:

```
[0:"{'test':'test'}", 1:"{'test':'test'}", 2:"{'test':'test'}",3: "{'test':'test'}"];
```

the output i need is :

```
{ test':'test', 'test':'test', 'test':'test', 'test':'test' }
```

Edit:
The final value will be associated to the ng-model automatically.

desired output example:

```
{
"unique_id": 172,
"portfolio": "DIGITAL",
"bus_unit": "dummy",
"project_phase": "",
"test_phase": "SIT",
"project": "Google",
"golivedate": "03/09/2016",
"performance": "Green",
"summary": "jgnbfklgnflknflk",
"last_updated": "",
"risks_issues": "gfmngfnfglkj",
"project_start": "03/16/2016",
"batchLast_run": "",
"custom_project": "1",
"test_execution_id": 5456,
"unique_id": 172,
"test_execution_id": 5456,
"pass": 8,
"fail": 8,
"blocked": 8,
"in_progress": 8,
"no_run": 8,
"not_available": 0,
"total": 8  
}
```

Comment: can you post your response properly ?

Comment: And also describe what exactly _i need to merge all values in to a single JSON file_ mean?

Comment: Should the final result be an object or a string?

Comment: You are getting downvoted because your question is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand you are trying to convert array of Json data into one singel json data. So you have array of values but you would want all of them in one variable. Try this

```js
var testData = ["{'test':'test'}", "{'test':'test'}", "{'test':'test'}", "{'test':'test'}"];

var finalData ="";

$.each(testData,function(index,value){
   finalData += value +',';
});

finalData = finalData.replace(/\},\{/g,',').slice(0, -1);

document.write(finalData);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: nope your answer outputs {'test':'test'},{'test':'test'},{'test':'test'},{'test':'test'}
what i need is {test':'test','test':'test','test':'test','test':'test'}

Comment: hi my response looks like
 [0:"{'test':'test'}", 1:"{'test':'test'}", 2:"{'test':'test'}",3: "{'test':'test'}"];

Comment: @VigneshRajarajan updated my answer. let me know if it helps

Comment: you're my Savior, my messiah :D

Comment: @VigneshRajarajan happy coding!! Mapule :D

Answer (score 1):

Map just applies the function to every element in the array.

```
var arrayOfJSON = ...
var arrayOfObjects = arrayOfJSON.map(function (jsonString){
    return JSON.parse(jsonString)
})
var jsonStringWithAllObjects = JSON.stringify(arrayOfObjects)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `underscore.js` then can easily

like:

```
var list = [{"test1": "test1"}, {"test2": "test2"}, {"test3": "test3"}];
var newList = _.extend.apply(null,[{}].concat(list));
```

then output will be

```
{ test1: "test1", test2: "test2", test3: "test3" }
```

Comment: Can you explain? I don't understand how that code works?

Comment: Copy all of the properties in the source objects over to the destination object, and return the destination object.

Comment: @shaishabroy that would be difficult because all the source objects have the same key. So destination in the end will just have one property. right??

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the array, convert every value to a JSON object, concatenate and then convert to a string back.

If you need fo this more times, you probably should make this a function.